# How can I get create table metadata queries in python using sqlAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, schema, database-metadata

I am using below code to get create table queries for `postgresql` database using `psycopg2` connection. How can I get the same using `SQLAlchemy`?

```
def get_create_table_queries():
    connection = connect_to_database()
    if connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            """
            SELECT
                'CREATE TABLE ' || table_name || ' (' || STRING_AGG(column_definition, ', ') || ');'
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    table_name,
                    column_name || ' ' || data_type ||
                    CASE
                        WHEN character_maximum_length IS NOT NULL THEN '(' || character_maximum_length || ')'
                        ELSE ''
                    END AS column_definition
                FROM information_schema.columns
                WHERE table_schema = 'public'
            ) AS table_columns
            GROUP BY table_name;
        """
        )
        create_table_queries = cursor.fetchall()
        connection.close()
        return create_table_queries
    else:
        return []

def get_create_table_queries():
    try:
        # Step 2: Create a SQLAlchemy Engine
        engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL"))

        # Step 3: Create a MetaData object without a bind
        metadata = MetaData()
        reflect = metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

        create_table_queries = []

        # Step 4: Use the inspect module to get table names
        inspector = inspect(engine)
        table_names = inspector.get_table_names()

        # Step 5: Reflect individual tables with a specific bind and retrieve CREATE TABLE queries
        for table_name in table_names:
            table = Table(table_name, metadata, autoload_with=engine)
            create_table_query = text(table.schema())
            create_table_queries.append(str(create_table_query))

        return create_table_queries
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting CREATE TABLE queries: {e}")
        return []
```

I tried above but getting errors.
Error getting `CREATE TABLE queries: 'NoneType' object is not callabl`